# Need clarification regarding JS merging and JS bundling in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, javascript, speedoptimization

I need to understand about JS merging, JS bundling and minify JS for site performance
Do we need to enable only one option from JS bundling and JS merging?
When i enable Js merging, my listing page does not work well.
When i enable JS bundling, my product pages does not load at all.
Which option should i select?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Merging and bundling typically causes worse performance in Magento 2, it's typically better to only enable minification and if you want bundling use a third party solution which you can read about on this question - [Magento 2.2 x or 2.3 - to bundle or not to bundle](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261673/magento-2-2-x-or-2-3-to-bundle-or-not-to-bundle/322113#322113)

Comment: Which tool will work best for this?

Comment: They mostly all work in the same way by generating a config for RequireJS Optimiser so they should give you very similar results.

Comment: Have you tried using baler? I installed baler, but then i was facing issue on shopping cart page. The JS on shopping cart could not load.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into problems too

Comment: What you did then?

Comment: We didn't bundle the JS :(

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please ellaborate. I am very much stuck with this. What i understand is you did not run this command bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_baler_js_bundling 1. Am i Right?